# My .c program create threads. But one of them is killed by system after 10 min running time. How to protect this thread?

Tags: raspbian, c

My .c program create threads. But one of them is killed by system after 10 min running time. How to protect this thread?
I creates some threads do period work. But one of them is killed by system. I notice this because the this thread does not print the period information after about 10 min running time.
How to protect this thread from being killed? Anybody met this before?

```
int main(void){

    /* threads */
    pthread_t thrid_up;
    pthread_t thrid_down;

    pthread_create( &thrid_up, NULL, (void * (*)(void *))thread_up, NULL);
    pthread_create( &thrid_down, NULL, (void * (*)(void *))thread_down, NULL);

    while (!exit_sig && !quit_sig) {
        //statistics
        ...
    }
}

void thread_up(void) {
    while (!exit_sig && !quit_sig) {
        //deal interrupt and send the messages to the server
        ...
    }
}

void thread_down(void) {
    while (!exit_sig && !quit_sig) {
        //deal the messages sent by the server
        ...
    }
}
```

The thread_up thread is killed by the system everytime when this program runs about 10 min long. But thread_down works well all the time.

Comment: This isn't a Pi specific question.  If you want an answer you will need to post a small example which demonstrates the problem.  You have almost certainly made an error in the code.

Comment: AFAIK threads are not *killed by system*, they can either terminate on their own, crash, or be destroyed by your application.

Comment: Are you sure the problem isn't in the `//deal interrupt and send the messages to the server ...` part?

Comment: The posted code does not compile.  There are several reasons.  1) the `...` in the code (several places) 2) missing the 'required' `#include` statements.

Comment: when calling system functions, like: `pthread_create()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: this kind of expression: `(void * (*)(void *))thread_up` is nonsense.  Suggest: `thread_up`  Similar considerations exist for the call to `pthread_create()` for the `thread_down`

Comment: toward the end of `main()` need two calls to `pthread_join()`

Comment: Note: only one line of execution will receive a signal, it does not propagate to all threads.  Probably better to have the `main()` include a signal handler function that passes 'new' signals to the child threads  and the main() thread call `pthread_join()` for each of the children.  Note: that not all signals can be caught